# Creating a Binary Indicator Column Based on Date Differences in PySpark DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, date, pyspark

I am working with a PySpark DataFrame that contains columns 'ID', 'date', and 'bool'. 'bool' is an indicator.

```
 #+-------+-------------+----+
 #|   ID  |     date    |bool|
 #+-------+-------------+----+
 #|1092829|  2019-10-29 |  0 |
 #|3091902|  2019-12-14 |  1 |
 #|3091902|  2020-07-13 |  0 |
 #|1092829|  2020-07-15 |  1 |
 #|1092829|  2020-07-17 |  1 |
 #|1092829|  2020-08-18 |  1 |
 #|  ...  |     ...     | ...|
 #+-------+-------------+----+
```

To simplify, let's imagine that I partition my dataframe over the variable ID and, to be even clearer, that I only consider ID 1092829. Note that the DataFrame is ordered in ascending order based on the dates.

```
 #+-------+-------------+----+
 #|   ID  |     date    |bool|
 #+-------+-------------+----+
 #|1092829|  2019-10-29 |  0 |
 #|1092829|  2019-12-14 |  1 |
 #|1092829|  2020-07-15 |  1 |
 #|1092829|  2020-07-17 |  1 |
 #|1092829|  2020-07-19 |  0 |
 #|1092829|  2020-08-15 |  1 |
 #|1092829|  2020-09-10 |  0 |
 #|1092829|  2020-09-15 |  0 |
 #|1092829|  2020-09-20 |  1 | 
 #|  ...  |     ...     | ...|
 #+-------+-------------+----+
```

**I want to create a column 'D' that is equal to 1 for a line X if the variable bool of a line Y (which is below line X) is equal to 1 and if the date difference between line X and line Y is less than 2 weeks, and 0 otherwhise.**

This would yield the following dataframe

```
 #+-------+-------------+----+---+
 #|   ID  |     date    |bool| D |
 #+-------+-------------+----+---+
 #|1092829|  2019-10-29 |  0 | 0 |
 #|1092829|  2019-12-14 |  1 | 0 |
 #|1092829|  2020-07-15 |  1 | 1 |
 #|1092829|  2020-07-17 |  1 | 0 |
 #|1092829|  2020-07-19 |  0 | 0 |
 #|1092829|  2020-08-15 |  1 | 0 |
 #|1092829|  2020-09-10 |  0 | 1 |
 #|1092829|  2020-09-15 |  0 | 0 |
 #|1092829|  2020-09-20 |  1 | 0 |
 #|  ...  |     ...     | ...|...|
 #+-------+-------------+----+---+
```

I know how to do it for a fixed number of rows and with the use of pyspark lag function but it's far from optimal as there might be 10 lines of observations in less than a 2 week span in the dataframe.

An example with two lags :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn("D", F.when((F.datediff(df.date, F.lag(df.date,-1))<14) & (F.lag(df.bool,-1)==1)\
| (F.datediff(df.date, F.lag(df.date,-2))<14) & (F.lag(df.bool,-2)==1),1).otherwise(0))
```

How could I do it for any number of rows in a computationally efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this logic is possible. Count bool = 1 between 2 weeks range and if it is larget than 1, it is the target.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('timestamp').rangeBetween(0, 14 * 86400)
​
df.withColumn('timestamp', f.unix_timestamp('date', 'y-M-d')) \
  .withColumn('bool_in_2weeks', f.count(f.when(f.col('bool') == f.lit(1), True)).over(w)) \
  .withColumn('D', f.expr('bool = 1 and bool_in_2weeks > 1').cast('int')) \
  .show(truncate=False)
+-------+----+----------+----------+--------------+---+
|ID     |bool|date      |timestamp |bool_in_2weeks|D  |
+-------+----+----------+----------+--------------+---+
|1092829|0   |2019-10-29|1572307200|0             |0  |
|1092829|1   |2019-12-14|1576281600|1             |0  |
|1092829|1   |2020-07-15|1594771200|2             |1  |
|1092829|1   |2020-07-17|1594944000|1             |0  |
|1092829|0   |2020-07-19|1595116800|0             |0  |
|1092829|1   |2020-08-15|1597449600|1             |0  |
|1092829|1   |2020-09-10|1599696000|1             |0  |
+-------+----+----------+----------+--------------+---+
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I modified it just a bit : a line X can have 'bool' = 0 and 'D' = 1 if in the two upcoming weeks, there is a line with 'bool'=1. I think there are clever ways to adapt you answer but this is what I came up with : ```df.withColumn('timestamp', f.unix_timestamp('date', 'y-M-d')) \
  .withColumn('bool_in_2weeks', f.count(f.when(f.col('bool') == f.lit(1), True)).over(w)) \
  .withColumn('D', f.when((f.col('bool_in2weeks')>1 & (F.col('bool')==1) | (F.col('bool')==0) & (F.col('bool_in_2weeks')>0),1).otherwhise(0)) \
 .show(truncate=False) ```

Answer (score 0):

I took your example and ran a few tests. This is what I came up with:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        {"ID": 1092829, "date": "2019-10-29", "bool": 0},
        {"ID": 1092829, "date": "2019-12-14", "bool": 1},
        {"ID": 1092829, "date": "2020-07-15", "bool": 1},
        {"ID": 1092829, "date": "2020-07-17", "bool": 1},
        {"ID": 1092829, "date": "2020-07-19", "bool": 0},
        {"ID": 1092829, "date": "2020-08-15", "bool": 1},
        {"ID": 1092829, "date": "2020-09-10", "bool": 1},
    ]
)
```

For your case, it is both simpler and more adequate to use [Window functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/functions.html#window-functions).
The window is constructed by partitioning your DataFrame according to your "ID" column. This will guarantee that no two different "ID" values will get their date/bool mixed up when applying the lag. Within the window, you need to sort the date in ascending order for the datediff operation.

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

window = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy(F.col("ID").asc(), F.col("date").asc())

transformed_df = df.withColumn(
    "D",
    F.coalesce(
        # Apply lag on "date" by -1 (bring next row's value to current row's level) to do `datediff` for the 2-week condition.
        (F.datediff(F.lag("date", -1, None).over(window), F.col("date")) < 14)
        # Apply lag on "bool" by -1 to compare, for a given row, if the next row has a 1 or not.
        & (
            F.lag("bool", -1, None).over(window) == F.lit(1)
        ),  # The comparisons and the "&" produce a boolean column
        F.lit(
            False
        ),  # For the case when the last `date` value for a given "ID" is NULL because of the lag, we set it to False by default.
    ).cast(
        "integer"
    ),  # Cast the boolean result into an integer for a binary value.
)

transformed_df.show()
```

Resulting DataFrame:

```
#+-------+----------+----+---+
#|     ID|      date|bool|  D|
#+-------+----------+----+---+
#|1092829|2019-10-29|   0|  0|
#|1092829|2019-12-14|   1|  0|
#|1092829|2020-07-15|   1|  1|
#|1092829|2020-07-17|   1|  0|
#|1092829|2020-07-19|   0|  0|
#|1092829|2020-08-15|   1|  0|
#|1092829|2020-09-10|   1|  0|
#+-------+----------+----+---+
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, this does not work as soon as more than one line separates line X from line Y (keeping in mind that the dataframe is ordered by dates). Indeed there might be 10 lines of observations in two weeks, and if the last one has 'bool'=1, I want all the lines before it to have 'D'=1.